# Entity framework, issue saving data in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have issue saving data in many-to-may relationship between two tables that breaks by introducing another table in between, containing primary keys of both. I have code first existing database approach along with repository pattern and unit of work in MVC application

[image]

and here is my model classes

### Navigation_Functions

```
public class Navigation_Functions
{
    public Navigation_Functions()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Function Title")]
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Hierarchy Level")]
    [Display(Name = "Hierarchy Level")]
    public int Hierarchy_Level { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
  }
}
```

### Navigation_FunctionController Model

```
 public class Navigation_FunctionController
{
    public Navigation_FunctionController()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public int ControllerID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

   public ICollection <Navigation_Functions> Navigation_Functions { get; set; }

}
```

### Junction Model

```
 [Table("Navigation_FunctionInController")]
public class Navigation_FunctionInController
{
    public Navigation_FunctionInController() 
    { 

    }

    [Key]
    public int FunctionInController_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Navigation_Functions")]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Navigation_FunctionController")]
    public int ControllerID { get; set; }

    public Navigation_FunctionController Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
    public Navigation_Functions Navigation_Functions { get; set; }

}
```

I have generic repository for CRUD operation

```
public void InsertEntity(TEntity obj)
    {
        _DbSet.Add(obj);
    }
```

### My ViewModel

```
public class FunctionsNavigation_ViewModel 
{
    public Navigation_Functions _Navigation_Functions { get; set; }

    public Navigation_FunctionController _Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
 public void CreateFunctionNavigation(FunctionsNavigation_ViewModel _obj)
  {
    using (var _uow = new FunctionsNavigation_UnitOfWork())
        {
            try
            {                  
                var _navigationFunction = _obj._Navigation_Functions;

               _navigationFunction.Navigation_FunctionController = new List<Navigation_FunctionController>();

               _navigationFunction.Navigation_FunctionController.Add(_obj._Navigation_FunctionController);

               _uow.Navigation_Functions_Repository.InsertEntity(_navigationFunction);

               _uow.Save(); 
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

if I remove following line from above code then it save new Navigation_Functions

```
 _navigationFunction.Navigation_FunctionController.Add(_obj._Navigation_FunctionController);
```

following is screen shot from debug code.

[image]

I am wondering if my ViewModel are correct? secondly How Entity Framework knows that it need to put primary keys of two tables in Navigation_FunctionInController?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You decribed what happens if you remove that line, but you did'd describe what you want to do and what goes wrong.

Comment: its basically doesn't save data in database. I want to store data of two tables along with primary key in junction table with primary keys of both

Comment: Try to add virtual keyword to collections in your models.
public virtual ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }  and  
public virtual ICollection <Navigation_Functions> Navigation_Functions { get; set; }  Does it help?

Comment: i check in a minute but I am just wondering if I need to modify my repositories classes !!!

Comment: no! it is not saving data to database....

Comment: Sorry than, no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: The two collections `ICollection <Navigation_Functions>` should be `ICollection <Navigation_FunctionInController>`. It's not a pure many to many association, its 1:n:1.

Comment: then how entity framework know in which table, it needs to put primary of two tables?????

Answer (score 0):

When your model looks like this...

```
public class Navigation_Functions
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
}

public class Navigation_FunctionController
{
    ...
    public ICollection <Navigation_Functions> Navigation_Functions { get; set; }
}
```

...so without a `Navigation_FunctionInController` class, the junction table in the database (`Navigation_FunctionInController`) is not represented in the class model. If you have this model code first, EF will create a junction table itself. If you work database first, EF won't create a junction class and in the diagram you will see a pure many to many association, like this: `*--*`. But this only happens if the junction table only contains the two foreign keys, both of which comprise a compound primary key.

In your model you have an explicit junction class (probably because the table has a primary key field besides the two foreign keys). This means that the many to many association turns into a 1:n:1 association. The class model should essentially look like this...

```
public class NavigationFunction
{
    ...
    public ICollection<NavigationFunctionInController> NavigationFunctionInControllers { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationFunctionController
{
    ...
    public ICollection <NavigationFunctionInController> NavigationFunctionInControllers { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationFunctionInController
{
    public int FunctionInControllerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NavigationFunction")]
    public int FunctionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NavigationFunctionController")]
    public int ControllerID { get; set; }

    public NavigationFunctionController NavigationFunctionController { get; set; }
    public NavigationFunction NavigationFunction { get; set; }

}
```

Note that the foreign key fields don't have to be part of the primary key (also not that I prefer the singular name `Navigation_Function` and plural names for collections, and no underscores in names).

So what happens in your code is that you have a `1:n:1` association, but you try to manage it like a `m:n` association by adding items directly to `_navigationFunction.Navigation_FunctionController`(s) . But EF doesn't track that collection, and the items are not saved.

Instead you have to create a junction class instance...

```
var nfic = new NavigationFunctionInController
            {
                NavigationFunction = obj.NavigationFunction,
                NavigationFunctionController = obj.Navigation_FunctionController
            };
```

...and save it through your repositories and UoW.